# Open multiple Files and perform macro on all opened Files

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro that will open 30 excel files which all have the same structure.

The macro should do operation on all files, and take the results from every file and put it in another excel file.That means: all Results (Values) will be copied into the destination file.

1. How do I write VBA code to open multiple files?
2. How do I take the results from every file and place them in my destination.xls file?

Comment: also - out of interest - do all the excel files have a common naming convention? How are you storing these file names? Array? Common naming would probably be best, like - MyFilei.xls were i is a number and you loop through them (For loop) and get the results in turn

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out [FileSearch.LookIn Property](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/HV080562483.aspx)
modify that example to something similar. (This would require that all your 30 files are in one folder though)

```
Dim WrkBook as Workbook
Set fs = Application.FileSearch
With fs
    .SearchSubFolders = False 
    .LookIn = "C:\My Documents" 'Path of folder to search
    .FileName = "*.xls" 'Limit to excel files
    If .Execute > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "There were " & .FoundFiles.Count & " file(s) found."
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
            WrkBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.FoundFiles(i))
            WrkBook.Worksheets(1).Select
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(DestinationRange) =   WrkBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(SourceRange).Value
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.print "There were no files found."
    End If
End With
```

You could also try

```
Workbooks("Destination.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(DestinationRange) = WrkBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(SourceRange).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after a solution, that requires the user to choose the files to open and process?

Try this...

```
Option Explicit

Sub opening_multiple_file()


Dim i As Integer

'Opening File dialog box
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Enabling multiple files select
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear

    'Only Excel files can be selected
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"

    If .Show = True Then
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            'Opening selected file
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
            'etc do other things with it
        Next i
    End If

End With

End Sub
```