# Copying cells from different files using Worbooks.Open in one with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I was searching for a macro that could open multiple files that I chose, copy a specific cell range "AJ9" from these files, paste it to my main file "KA_AcceleratingReading_V1" sheet "Graph provision" and then close all the files that I opened previously to only have this main file with a column of my data range "A" so I can do a graphic with it.

I found this post: [Open multiple Files and perform macro on all opened Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318876/vba-open-multiple-files-and-perform-macro-on-all-opened-files/61946230#61946230?newreg=580d972879874e048d72a6b34fff24b0) that had an interesting code but I still can't figure how to finish it. Everything that I tried did not work.

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub copy_multiple_file()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'Opening File dialog box
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Enabling multiple files select
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Clear
    
        'Only Excel files can be selected
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
    
        If .Show = True Then
            For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                'Opening selected file
                Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
            Next i
        End If
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to elaborate, where is the cell you want to copy? Is it on the first worksheet of the opened workbook? What is the range of this cell? Where do you want to copy the values to in your main file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Inside the loop, add the code necesary to copy the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out a solution, here is the code i used:

```
Sub open_multiple_file()

Dim i As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim DerniereLigne As String

'Opening File dialog box
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Enabling multiple files select
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear

    'Only Excel files can be selected
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
    If .Show = True Then
    
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            
            'Searh for the last row
            DerniereLigne = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Open the selected file
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
            'Erased the .xlsx from the name file
            name = Left(ActiveWorkbook.name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
            
                          
            'Copy and past at the last empty cell
            Range("AJ9").Copy
            Workbooks("KA_AcceleratedReading_V1 - Copy").Sheets("Graph provision").Cells(DerniereLigne, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    
            
            'Close the file that we previously opened
            Workbooks(name).Close

        Next i

    End If

End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You have skipped the question of the worksheet name in the source workbooks. The results may be wrong if the wrong worksheet is active (selected) upon opening. Do they all have the same name and which is it (e.g. `Sheet1`)?

Comment: Yes they all have the same worksheetname: "Balance globale par pièce - sub"

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code with your code and copy data,

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
inputFolder = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\"

inputFile = Dir(inputFolder & "*.xls*")

' This will loop all excel files in the folder one by one
Do While (inputFile <> "")  
        
        'Copy data from files one by one and paste

        inputFile = Dir
loop
```

you can find data you want in files by `instr()` command inside the do while loop

Comment: Thank you for helping me but i don't understand where exactly should i add it and what should i modify so it works.

Comment: Add it inside the Do while loop, in place of the comment  ```'Copy data from files one by one and paste``` .  Add my code instead of yours, It should work

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Cell Value From Multiple Files

- It is assumed that `KA_AcceleratingReading_V1.xlsm` is the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).
- Double-check the worksheet names because they have no french characters here and don't forget about the 31 characters limit.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub CopyCellValueFromMultipleFiles()

    ' Create a FileDialog object ('fd') as a File Picker dialog box...
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        
        ' Set some of the FileDialog object properties.
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
        
        ' Display the File Picker dialog box and check if the user canceled.
        If .Show <> True Then
            MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        ' Reference the destination first cell ('dCell').
        Dim dCell As Range
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph provision")
            Set dCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
        
        ' Copy (by assignment) each value from the current source cells
        ' to the current destination cell.
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        Dim Item As Variant
    
        For Each Item In .SelectedItems
            With Workbooks.Open(Item) ' open (and reference)
                dCell.Value = .Worksheets("Balance globale par piece - sub") _
                    .Range("AJ9").Value ' copy
                .Close SaveChanges:=False ' close
            End With
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1) ' next destination cell
        Next Item
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End With
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


Sub CopyCellValueFromMultipleFilesStudy()

    ' Create a FileDialog object ('fd') as a File Picker dialog box.
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    ' Set some of the FileDialog object properties.
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
        
    ' Display the File Picker dialog box and check if the user canceled.
    If fd.Show <> True Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Reference the FileDialogSelectedItems collection ('SelectedFiles').
    Dim SelectedFiles As FileDialogSelectedItems
    Set SelectedFiles = fd.SelectedItems
    
    ' Set the object variable to Nothing since
    ' what we need is in the the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
    'Set fd = Nothing ' not necessary
    
    ' Reference the destination workbook ('swb').
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('sws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Graph provision")
    ' Reference the destination first cell ('dCell').
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    ' Turn off screen updating to speed up the code.
    ' You won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Declare additional variables to be used in the loop.
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim SelectedFile As Variant
    
    ' Loop through the items ('SelectedFile'), actually file paths (strings),
    ' of the FileDialogSelectedItems collection...
    For Each SelectedFile In SelectedFiles
        
        ' Open and reference the source workbook ('swb').
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFile)
        ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
        Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Balance globale par piece - sub")
        ' Reference the source cell ('sCell').
        Set sCell = sws.Range("AJ9")
        ' Write the value to a variable ('sValue').
        sValue = sCell.Value
        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        ' Copy the value by assignment.
        dCell.Value = sValue
        ' Reference the next destination cell, the cell below the current one.
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
     
    Next SelectedFile
        
    ' Turn on screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I just tested and everything works perfectly, thanks! But i don't get what is the difference between the two programs that you wrote