# Delete duplicate rows based on more than one column with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an excel macro that can delete duplicate rows and their original ones based on more than one column.

In the table below you will find the example data and the output for which I'm looking. I need to delete all duplicate rows but only look at some columns like in the example the first 3 headers.

Input table

| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 50 | 20 | 1 |
| Test | 50 | 20 | 2 |
| Test | 30 | 20 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 4 |
| 2 | 20 | 30 | 5 |
| Test23 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| Test23 | 5 | 5 | 7 |

Output table after executing the macro

| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 30 | 20 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 4 |
| 2 | 20 | 30 | 5 |

I have tried to create a macro, but that only deletes the duplicate values and the original one stays. And I need to delete original one as well.

Sub RemoveDuplicatesMultipleColumns()
Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = Range("A1:D8")
dataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, we can create a dummy variable first & calculate the frequency of first 3 columns using countifs, later filter & delete all rows whose count is >1... Not sure if their is any direct way though... As you mentioned inbuilt procedure of VBA's RemoveDuplicates can't get rid of original rows too... So maybe try this code then;

```
Sub delete_dup_rows()

Columns(5).ClearContents
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E2").Formula = "=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,$B2,$C:$C,$C2)"
Range("E2").Copy
Range("E2:E" & lRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select

Set Rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">1"
Rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Rng.AutoFilter

Columns(5).ClearContents
End Sub
```

This is the output of your input data;

[image]

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thank you for the macro, it works with this table, I'm now trying to adapt it to something similar. I can forward my example excel file if you could help me. I've tried but deleted only 2 of the rows, and it should delete 4. I should be left with only one. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7b3931dd6cba29b0824d1cb1fa945f3020220929074729/21f622

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7b3931dd6cba29b0824d1cb1fa945f3020220929074729/21f622

Comment: I think it's because I'm trying to apply a filter on an empty row, that's why it's not working. Is there a way to apply a filter on that empty row over the data. Or maybe add some test with the macro and delete it after?

Comment: I've managed to make it work. Just one question is here a way to remove duplicates not by only more then 1 number, but maybe have value 2 or 4 or 6 basically even numbers only.

Comment: @Shwapx I'm not able to download that file... anyway, glad to help... & for the criteria of filter, you can edit the code something like this... Rng.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("2", "4", "6"), Operator:=xlFilterValues for filtering out 2/4/6... any other criteria, you have to edit Array part...

Comment: Thanks for that. Just one last questions is there a way to add the name of the excel file and name of sheet in the VBA so maybe I can export it and run it outside of excel. Export the macro I mean and just run it and macro automatically open excel and does the magic :). Since I will need to adjust this to 400+ excel files I can try to include both name of the file and the name of the sheet. And in my case they are the same if the name is "Dog" sheet with be named "Dog" as well. And at the end maybe i can try combining all macros in one big file and run it over those 400+ files.

Comment: Try this link... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318876/open-multiple-files-and-perform-macro-on-all-opened-files) for opening excel files one by one & run certain macro on each excel...

Comment: Thanks. I didn't express my self correctly sorry about that. I wanted to ask if there is an option to include in that macro the name of the excel file and the sheet in which macro to operate. So i can export the macro and run it out of excel. 

Let's say i have folder which have 3 excel files and that macro. When i run the macro to run it over the correct excel file and sheet. This will save the time of opening the excel and runing the macro manaully. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about exporting the macro & run it out of excel actually... But, do know that with that link you just have to open only one excel (say, master file), where your code is written & the macro itself will open the excels in the given pathname & update the data as required in the mentioned sheet name...

Comment: Thanks i have found what i need. Thank you again!

Comment: Hello @Sachin Kohli, I end up with some excel files having the first column empty so the actual data start from column B, and in that case the macro copy the formula up not down where the data is it and end up with an incorrect filter and data. How i can adjust it.

Comment: I've make it to work with just adding script to delete first column and adjust the cells, but i guess there should be smarter way :D